# Nexus to proxy yarn registry

Tags: java, registry, yarnpkg, nexus, maven-frontend-plugin

I have a Java app with a JavaScript frontend. I am using the [maven-frontend-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin)
to download node and yarn, to install yarn modules and to build the frontend with yarn. By default, yarn searches for the node modules such as `@material-ui/core/-/core-4.11.3.tgz` in registry `https://registry.yarnpkg.com`. Now I want to use my proxy registry on Nexus instead of the remote registry `https://registry.yarnpkg.com`.

As an attempt, I added a `.npmrc` file containing an entry `registry` pointing to the Nexus registry, but the `yarn install` phase ignores it and still looks for the dependencies in the remote registry `https://registry.yarnpkg.com`.

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Do find solution ? .yarnrc file maybe ? I try without success...

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque, no, no improvement